# How to use two different sets of mailer templates for two different Devise models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, resque

I'm using Resque to send Devise emails. To do so I set:

devise.rb

```
config.mailer = "Mailers::Devise::DeviseMailer"
```

But I have 2 devise models -- User and Client. I want to send different devise mailer templates for each.

devise.rb says "The first four configuration values can also be set straight in your models.", and config.mailer is one of those first four, but I'm not sure how to set that in the model directly.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick was to set:

devise.rb

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

For more info see: 'Configuring views' in the devise doc at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

> If you have more than one role in your application (such as “User” and
>   “Admin”), you will notice that Devise uses the same views for all
>   roles. Fortunately, Devise offers an easy way to customize views. All
>   you need to do is set “config.scoped_views = true” inside
>   “config/initializers/devise.rb”.
>
> After doing so, you will be able to have views based on the role like
>   “users/sessions/new” and “admins/sessions/new”. If no view is found
>   within the scope, Devise will use the default view at
>   “devise/sessions/new”. You can also use the generator to generate
>   scoped views:

Answer (score 9):

I have created an example app that does this:

https://github.com/rodrigoflores/multiple-mailer

Please pay attention to https://github.com/rodrigoflores/multiple-mailer/blob/master/app/models/user.rb#L6 and the similar line on app/models/admin.rb where you can choose the mailer for each devise model. You will also have to read Devise mailers (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/mailers/devise/mailer.rb) source code to implement the same methods. And finally, write your views for the mailers.